# Cannot assign to self out of a method in the init family?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using self like "`self = [super init];`", the following code give me an error "`cannot assign to self out of a method in the init family`"

```
- (id)showDropDown:(UIButton *)b:(CGFloat *)height:(NSArray *)arr:(NSString *)direction {
    btnSender = b;
    animationDirection = direction;
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        CGRect btn = b.frame;
        self.list = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];

        if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y, btn.size.width, 0);
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, -5);
        }else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width, 0);
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, 5);
        }

        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

        table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width, 0)];
        table.delegate = self;
        table.dataSource = self;
        table.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        table.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.239 green:0.239 blue:0.239 alpha:1];
        table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        table.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y-*height, btn.size.width, *height);
        } else if([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width, *height);
        }
        table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width, *height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [b.superview addSubview:self];
        [self addSubview:table];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requesting the window of a view (<NIDropDown: 0x684ac50; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>) with a nil layer. This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:.
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If your method is an initializer, it must start with `init`:

`- (instancetype)initWithDropDown:(UIButton *)b:(CGFloat *)height:(NSArray *)arr:(NSString *)direction`

Otherwise, you can change it to be a class method, and return a new instance:

```
+ (instancetype)showDropDown:(UIButton *)b:(CGFloat *)height:(NSArray *)arr:(NSString *)direction
{
    btnSender = b;
    animationDirection = direction;
    YourClassName obj = [[self alloc] init];
    if (obj) {
        // Initialization code
        // …
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Also, if the character immediately following `init` is NOT capitalised, you will get the same error (`initwithDropDown:` for example). Took me bloomin ages to find that badboy...

Comment: Don't forget to make sure your function returns id.

Comment: I will STRESS @TimWindsorBrown 's comment, Make sure the next character after init IS!!! capitalized.  (initWithSomething) don't mistakenly type (initwithsomething)

Answer (score 7):

You can't initialize `self` outside an `init` method because of the following [convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH39-SW1):

> If an object’s class does not implement an initializer, the
>   Objective-C runtime invokes the initializer of the nearest ancestor
>   instead.

and because the name of some methods is recognized by the memory management system of the runtime:

> When the name of a method starts with alloc init, retain, or copy, it
>   means it's being created for the caller, who has the responsibility to
>   release the object when he is done with it. Otherwise the method
>   returned is not owned by the caller, and he has to indicate he wants
>   to keep it calling retain on the object.

Therefore, all initializers should be written as a variation of this:

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        _someVariable = @"someValue";
    }
    return self;
}
```

- Don't use `if ((self = [super init]))` because it's ugly.
- Don't use `self.someVariable` because the object may not be initialized yet. Use direct variable access instead (`_someVariable`).
- We write `self = [super init]` and not just `[super init]` because a different instance may be returned.
- We write `if (self)` because there will be cases where it will return `nil`.

However, there are two more problems with your method:

- You are combining object creation (`[super init]`) and an action (`-showDropDown::::`) in the same method. You should write two separate methods instead.
- The name of your method is `-showDropDown::::`. Objective-C programmers expect self documenting method names like `-showDropDown:height:array:direction:` instead. I guess you come from a different language, but *when in Rome, do as Romans do*, or else you won't be playing along with the rest of the team.

Answer (score 3):

Check your spelling in this method

```
-(id)initwithArray:(NSArray *)array
```

Code: (Objective-C)

```
-(id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to rename your initializer (currently named `showDropDown`) to something that starts with `init` (like `initWithDropDown…`). This used to be just a convention (albeit a reasonable one), but now with ARC it’s a hard requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone made mistake similar to me, It might be helpful. Please change `-(void)` to `-(id)`. You need to make sure that you are returning an `id`.If you use `-(void)`  for both **declaration** and **definition** of **initialiser**, compiler will give you same error as mentioned in question, without telling you to change return type.